# Display relationship attribute in django template

Tags: python, django

So, in my models I have:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    articleNumber = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    costPerUnity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='Recipe_Ingredient', related_name='recipes')

class Recipe_Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField()

    GRAM = 'g'
    KILOGRAM = 'kg'
    LITER = 'l'
    CENTILITER = 'cl'

    UNITY_CHOICES = (
        (GRAM, 'Gram(s)'),
        (KILOGRAM, 'Kilogram(s)'),
        (LITER, 'Liter(s)'),
        (CENTILITER, 'Centiliter(s)'),
    )

    quantityUnit = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=UNITY_CHOICES,
        default=GRAM,
    )
```

In my template:

```
{% for ingredient in recipe.ingredients.all %}
    <li>{{ ingredient.name }} -  # quantity goes here </li>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I show the quantity atribute of the Recipe_Ingredient associated with this recipe and ingredient?
In the shell I could do this query: Recipe_Ingredient.objects.get(ingredient=Ingredient.objects.get(name='Cenoura'), recipe=Recipe.objects.get(name='Teste')), but I'm not quite sure how to do it in the template and what's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Can you include the Recipe and Ingredient model in your question?

Comment: Hi @schillingt, I just included it in my question. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by iterating over the `Receipe_Ingredient` relationship.

```
{% for recipe_ingredient in recipe.recipe_ingredient_set.all %}
    <li>{{ recipe_ingredient.ingredient.name }} -  {{ recipe_ingredient.quantity }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!